# Python-How to access a folder inside a zip file and write into it

Tags: python

Hi I was trying to access a file from z.jar.
The File Structure is like z.jar\org(folder).
Here Org is a folder, i was trying to access the org folder inside z.jar and trying  to write something. Can anyone help me in this?

```
import zipfile
def show_jar_classes(jar_file):
    """prints out .class files from jar_file"""
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'w')
    try:
        #Code to write inside org folder in inside z.jar
        zf.write('India.txt')
    finally:
        zf.close()

jar_file='D:/pyt/z.jar'
show_jar_classes(jar_file)
```

Comment: do you get an error? What do you get?

Comment: I didn't try . Because i know only how to open a jar file not the folder inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting your code. Using `writestr` works for me:

```
import zipfile, os

def show_jar_classes(jar_file):
    """prints out .class files from jar_file"""
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'w')
    try:
        #Code to write inside org folder in inside z.jar
        filename = 'Org\\India.txt' # name of the file
        fcontent = b'India is a great country' # content
        zf.writestr(filename,fcontent,zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    finally:
        zf.close()

jar_file = 'D:/pyt/z.jar'
show_jar_classes(jar_file)
```

Comment: Hi giosans, thanks for your respond. I tried with your code as below
import zipfile
import os

def show_jar_classes(jar_file):


    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'w')

    try:
        #Code to write inside org folder in inside z.jar
        filename = 'org\India.txt' # name of the file
        fcontent = b'India is a great country' # content
        zf.writestr(filename,fcontent,zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    finally:
        zf.close()
jar_file='D:/python/try'
show_jar_classes(jar_file)
Instead of writing it into try,jar  it has created another file with the same name try

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Yes, it would work without a `try`. Does it create the file inside the folder `Org`? If so, this answer your question. Or not?!

Comment: No it did not create the file inside Org instead it creates a new file outside z.jar with the same name z

Comment: Strange, because it is done with the zipped file object `zf`. It did work for me. Can you perhaps share the `z.jar`?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M5oSJsat0xQQ3gn8W2TZcSKrm-aP8YjM/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: It does work for me. Your issue might also depend on the kde. I'm running on spyder, Python2.7, Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing 'w' mode with 'a' mode helped me to solve the problem I had:

```
import zipfile, os

def show_jar_classes(jar_file):

    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(jar_file, 'a')
    try:
        #Code to write inside org folder in inside z.jar
        filename = 'org\\India.txt' # name of the file
        fcontent = 'India is a great country' # content
        zf.writestr(filename,fcontent,zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    finally:
        zf.close()

jar_file = 'D:/python/z.jar'

show_jar_classes(jar_file)
```

Comment: 'a' appends to a file. That means it was there already. My answer was correct.